# Was "3062oldtile" in any sets?

Tags: set-identification, vintage

Was the [3062oldtile - Brick, Round 1 x 1 No Bottom Lip or Stud (Tile)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062oldtile#T=S&C=5&O=%7B%22color%22:5,%22iconly%22:0%7D) in any sets?  Bricklink doesn't show it in any sets.  Did LEGO sell this part individually a long time ago or is the database merely incomplete here?

[image: 3062oldtile image]

Comment: Same person who added this to bricklink as the one and only selling it, I call shenanigans

Comment: I think the database is known to be incomplete that far back in time. But like @MichaelVerschaeve I don't believe much in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a prototype / part that was not put in production

[Post / Picture by Gary Istok on Eurobricks](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/73724-unknown-old-lego-1x1-elements/)

[image]

Comment: That's a great picture.  Thanks for finding this.